# how to install pydot & graphviz on google colab?

Tags: python, keras, graphviz, google-colaboratory, pydot

I'm trying plot my model on the google colab.

```
 from keras.utils import plot_model
 plot_model(model, to_file="model.png")
```

and I got this error:

```
 ImportError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.
```

I've installed `pydot-ng` and `graphviz` and I'm still can't get through this error.

Comment: Have you tried to import the pydot module from the python shell? If you cannot import from there, probably this means that this is an environment problem

Comment: @Nikaidoh python shell? google colab is something like Jupyter notebook.So, I don't think I can access the python shell. But I can import pydot in the notebook.

Comment: It's the same. :) try to import pydot from the notebook. Probably you will not able to import the module from there. Which means that you haven't correctly installed the dependency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To install `pydot`, run:

```
!pip install -q pydot
```

Then, restart your VM to reload keras which should then detect pydot's existence. (Runtime menu -> Restart runtime...)

Comment: !pip install graphviz
!apt-get install graphviz 
then restart VM,it worked!

Comment: RESTART VM is essential here. 
I was on a Jupyter Notebook and I simply "restarted kernel"
And finally it worked for me